# TransitionManager and ConstraintLayout with Guideline not working

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout, android-transitions

I am trying to get a view from full screen to half screen using `TransitionManager` `ConstraintLayout` and `Guideline`

this should be straight forward. Move from constraint to bottom parent, to the 50% guideline. 
Check out the video of the result. It reduces the height to 1dp.

[image]

My first layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><!--
  ~ (c) Facebook, Inc. and its affiliates. Confidential and proprietary.
  -->

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:ignore="BadClassUsageInResource-FrameLayout">

    <!-- foreground image -->
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/foreground_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="#ff0000"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

My second layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><!--
  ~ (c) Facebook, Inc. and its affiliates. Confidential and proprietary.
  -->

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- foreground image -->
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/foreground_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="50dp"
        android:background="#ff0000"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/middle_guideline"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:background="#9944FF"
        android:text="skdfjhskdjfhksjd"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/middle_guideline" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/middle_guideline"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

The transition when clicking:

```
ConstraintSet constraintSet = new ConstraintSet();
constraintSet.clone(this, R.layout.second);
TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(mroot);
constraintSet.applyTo((ConstraintLayout) mroot);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that the guideline is present in both of the layout files with the same id. The guideline should be horizontal and not vertical.

You should also clone the *ConstraintSet* from the layout that you are transitioning to. (It's not clear that this is the case.)

```
val constraintSet = ConstraintSet()
// Clone from the layout that we are transitioning to.
constraintSet.clone(this, R.layout.activity_main_2)
TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(mroot)
constraintSet.applyTo(mroot as ConstraintLayout?)
```

Do these things and it should work.

---

I should add that the your second layout with the *TextView* is only used for its constraints. The *TextView* will not appear in your layout after the transition. If you do want the *TextView* to appear, you will need to add it to the first layout.

Comment: That worked! Thanks. I didn't realize it needs to be specified in the first layout.
I fixed the layout names to reflect which is second. 

The TextView I am trying to make fade in + move, so it looks like it slides into appearance. But all I get is fade in . 
I tried adding it to the original main_activity with a different location, and GONE /INVISIBLE but all I get is fade in. 

Is it possible to do fade and slide?

Comment: @Alon _beginDelayedTransition_ is very easy to use but does make some assumptions. You should be able to get a slide-in effect with a little more work. Take a look at  [Transitions in the Android Support Library](https://medium.com/google-developers/transitions-in-the-android-support-library-8bc86a1d688e) for some clues about how you might go about this.

Comment: Thanks. I'll have a look. 
I was successful in getting the fade+move only on enter screen animations. I"ll look at your link for more precise fave+move in center screen.... 
Thanks for referral